# Propagating events through overlapping svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have two overlapping `svg.g` groups with different `onclick` events. I periodically blend the groups in or out of the visualization using the `opacity` attribute. Currently, only the `onclick` event of the group that is rendered on top is called, but I would like to call the event for the group that is currently visible. Alternatively, I could always call both events and use a conditional statement inside the called function which depended on the `opacity` attribute.

Here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var canvas_w = 1280 - 80,
        canvas_h = 800 - 180;

    var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", canvas_w)
        .attr("height", canvas_h)   

    var visible_group = svg.append("g")
        .attr("opacity", 1)
        .on("click", function(d){console.log("Click")})
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .style("fill", "blue");

    var invisible_group = svg.append("g")
        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .on("click", function(d){console.log("Invisiclick")})
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .style("fill", "red");


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will render a blue rectangle, the visible group. The group with the red rectangle is hidden. If you click on the blue rectangle, "Invisiclick" will be printed to the console, the `onclick` event of the hidden group. I would like to print "Click" to the console, or alternatively, both "Invisiclick" and "Click".

How can I do this?

Comment: You can also just put `pointer-events: none` On the invisible group. Even if you want to leave them ghosted in, it would still make them transparent from a mouse event point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity does make the elements *translucent*, it doesn't make them *disappear*. Just as you can tap a piece of glass, you can click an element with `opacity:0`.

Now, there are two options, based on whether the **shapes are different** in both views. If they **aren't** (say, you're drawing a world map, the countries stay the same, just the color changes), it might be easiest to listen to the topmost layer and then run an if-statement which part to execute. Like this

```js
    var state = "blue";


    var clickHandler = function() {
        if(state === "blue") {
            console.log("Blue clicked");
        } else {
            console.log("Red clicked");
        }
    }


    var toggleState = function() {
        state = (state === "blue") ? "red" : "blue";
    }

    var updateDisplay = function() {
        blueGroup
            .transition()
            .duration(400)
            .attr("opacity", state === "blue" ? 1 : 0);
        redGroup
            .transition()
            .duration(400)
            .attr("opacity", state === "red" ? 1 : 0);
    }

    var canvas_w = 1280 - 80,
        canvas_h = 120;

    var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", canvas_w)
        .attr("height", canvas_h)   

    var blueGroup = svg.append("g")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("opacity", 1)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .style("fill", "blue");

    var redGroup = svg.append("g")
        .on("click", clickHandler)
        .append("rect")
        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .style("fill", "red");



    d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
        toggleState();
        updateDisplay();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://samizdat.cz/tools/d3/3.5.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
<button>change!</button>
```

If on the other hand the **shapes change**, you will need to first make the elements translucent with `opacity:0` and *then* make them *disappear* with `display:none` (otherwise, they will flash out instantly). An alternative is [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events), but only if you don't need to support [old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). 
The transition would then look like this:

```js
var state = "blue";

var toggleState = function() {
    state = (state === "blue") ? "red" : "blue";
}

var updateDisplay = function() {
    blueGroup
        .style("display", state === "blue" ? "block" : "none")
        .transition()
        .duration(400)
        .attr("opacity", state === "blue" ? 1 : 0)
        .each("end", function() {
            blueGroup.style("display", state === "blue" ? "block" : "none");
        });
        
    redGroup
        .style("display", state === "red" ? "block" : "none")
        .transition()
        .duration(400)
        .attr("opacity", state === "red" ? 1 : 0)
        .each("end", function() {
            redGroup.style("display", state === "red" ? "block" : "none");
        });
}

var canvas_w = 1280 - 80,
    canvas_h = 120;

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", canvas_w)
    .attr("height", canvas_h)   

var blueGroup = svg.append("g")
    .on("click", function() {
        console.log("Blue clicked");
    })
    .append("rect")
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "blue");

var redGroup = svg.append("g")
    .on("click", function() {
        console.log("Red clicked");
    })
    .append("rect")
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .style("display", "none")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 120)
    .style("fill", "red");



d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    toggleState();
    updateDisplay();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
<button>change!</button>
```

Note that on each transition, we now have to handle both `opacity` *and* `display`, and in correct order. Also note that now we have listeners on *both* `rect`s.

The example would be quite a bit simpler if it could be used with `.enter()` and `.exit()` selections, as you could make away with the `.on("end")` and instead use `.remove()` on the exiting transitions.

Update: practically identical to `display:none` is also `visibility: hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the style [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility) rather than the attribute `opacity` to set the groups as hidden or visible, you can also use the style [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) to restrict events to visible elements.

```
var canvas_w = 1280 - 80,
    canvas_h = 800 - 180;

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", canvas_w)
    .attr("height", canvas_h)   

var visible_group = svg.append("g")
    .style("visibility", "visible")
    .style("pointer-events", "visible")
    .on("click", function(d){console.log("Click")})
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "blue");

var invisible_group = svg.append("g")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("pointer-events", "visible")
    .on("click", function(d){console.log("Invisiclick")})
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "red");


</script>
```

This example will print "Click" to the console when you click the blue rectangle.